# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c

i am new to c, i am trying to make a simple code in which i replace the vowels of an input with the * character... i am having trouble with the array (i am mainly familiar with python only using c now.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

 char* main() {
 int c;
 char* vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

 while( 1 ) {   // means: true
  c = getchar();
  if(c == EOF) break;
  if(c = vowels) putchar('*'); 
  else putchar(c);
}
}
```

i keep receiving the same error message: novowels.c:5:41: note: (near initialization for ‘vowels[4]’)
novowels.c:10:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       if(c = vowels) putchar('*'); 
            ^

.... please help, i can't quite figure out how do complete this program of replacing vowels with *

Comment: And the Python tag just slipped in? Do not add unrealted tags!

Comment: "// means: true" So why not use `true` and `stdbool.h` then?

Comment: @Olaf Becausethat's C99 and OP may not have learned about C99 yet? There are thousands of reasons not to use the weird type `_Bool`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: `true` is an `int`, not `_Bool`. It is just standard C. And can you recify calling the unsigned integer type `_Bool` "weird"?

Comment: @Olaf `_Bool` has different conversion rules from any other type. It also has a more restricted range than `char` which is something that breaks with the conventions of C (i.e. `char` being the most narrow type).

Comment: @FUZxxl: Similar to `bool` in C++. It just sticks as close to C++ `bool` as possible without breaking established conversions.

Comment: @Olaf It already breaks all the conventions. `_Bool` shouldn't be used.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I don't see how `_Bool`'s being more narrow than `char` can break any conventions. What conventions are based on `char`'s status of being the most narrow type? There's no reason to avoid `bool` (aka `_Bool`) in C. One can actually argue that `_Bool` should be preferred over `bool` to avoid conflicts with C++ in cross-compilable headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `char *main()` is illegal in C. It should be `int main()`.

Secondly, `'a'` and the like are *integer* constants in C. You cannot use them to initialize and array of `char *` elements. If you wanted a `char` array you should have declared it as

```
const char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
```

If you wanted a string array you should have declared it as

```
const char *const vowels[] = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
```

Finally, it is completely unclear what you were trying to say by `c = vowels`. If you want to check whether `c` is in `vowels` array, keep in mind that there's no core language feature that can do it for you (and certainly not the `=` operator). You have to implement the check manually or use an applicable library feature.

For example, one possible way to check it is

```
const char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
...
if (memchr(vowels, c, sizeof vowels) != NULL)
  putchar('*');
```

Alternatively, it can be expressed as

```
const char *const vowels = "aeiou";
...
if (strchr(vowels, c) != NULL)
  putchar('*');
```

Comment: `char *main()` is illegal in C++, but might not be illegal in C. It is implementation-defined. (N1256 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your program contains a typo. `==` is comparison whereas `=` is assignment. Instead of this line

```
if(c = vowels) putchar('*');
```

you probably meant to write

```
if(c == vowels) putchar('*');
```

but even that is incorrect. You cannot use the `==` operator to test for membership. To test for membership, you could use the `strchr()` function from `<string.h>`:

```
if (memchr(vowels, c, sizeof vowels) != NULL) putchar('*');
```

You can read [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memchr.html) about what `memchr` does.

Lastly, as `AnT` already remarked, `main` shouldn't return a `char*`. The `main` function must return an `int` in a strictly conforming C program. Change the line

```
char* main() {
```

to

```
int main() {
```

to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not comparing anything in `c = vowels`. You are assigning to `c` the address of the array `vowels` (which is a pointer indeed).

Probably you wanted to check equality between c and one of the vowels but you must use the `[]` operator since `vowels` is an array, an index, and a different operator (comparison, which is `==`). Something like:

```
if (c == vowels[2])
```

but then vowels should be a `char[]` not a `char*[]`.